# Xamarin not installing on visual studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community and trying to install Xamarin. I am getting this message please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

To install Xamarin internet is required please check internet is connection

Because it will download Android SDK , Java SDK , latest Xamarin release and install

Comment: android SDK java SDK are already installed. internet connection is fine

Comment: Are you connecting behind a firewall / proxy? Some AV applications can cause havoc with connections too.